# What rotation angle of the second square relative to the first maximizes the area covered by two inscribed squares in a circle?

Tags: optimization, area

Aside, How do we generalize this problem to n-squares inside a circle?

[image]

> Two identical squares are inscribed in a circle in such a way that the area of the circle not covered by either square is minimized to the greatest extent possible. Approximately what proportion of the circle's area is covered by the inscribed squares?

---

[image]

Related question with 30-60-90 triangles.

Since the side lengths of the squares must be the same, and they are both 6 , we have a system of equations;
$$
\begin{gathered}
y+x+y \sqrt{3}=6 \\
\frac{x \sqrt{3}}{2}+2 y+\frac{x}{2}=6
\end{gathered}
$$
We solve this to get $x=6-2 \sqrt{3}$ and $y=3-\sqrt{3}$.
The area of each triangle is $\frac{x}{2} \cdot \frac{x \sqrt{3}}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{2}=6 \sqrt{3}-9$ by plugging in $x$.

https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/2021_Fall_AMC_10B_Problems/Problem_18

Comment: Related to a recent AMC 10 problem, fall 2021A p18 iirc

Comment: The question has two parts: At what angle is the area covered by the squares maximised (is it really the obvious symmetric configuration)? And what is the actual area in that case? The latter can be answered by splitting into several triangles of area $(\tan 45^\circ -\tan\alpha)\frac{r^2}4$

Comment: what is $\alpha$? what maximum takes place at $\dfrac{\pi}{2}$ @HagenvonEitzen